# Searching for mails with two or more attachments - thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email, attachment

My Problem: I need to find all mails with two or more attachments. And I need to do so maybe 20 times a day for more than 10000 mails.

Can I make Thunderbird show the number of attachments a single mail has in inbox and not only if there is an attachment or not? And if Thunderbird isn't able to do so - is there any other ubuntu mail client that is?

Or is there any other way - like making a filter that marks mails which have 2 or more attachments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [attachment count](http://attachmentcount.mozdev.org/) add-on which gives an other column to the existing ones.
The required steps are the following:

1. For TB 22+ in terminal: `wget http://downloads.mozdev.org/attachmentcount/AttachmentCount-1.7.xpi`
2. Then you install the add-on from: Tools / Add-ons / Extensions /
   install add-on from file (in the button next to the search field) which should be located in your home folder.
3. Finally in the column chooser (where you normally have subject, date etc.) you add the column attachment counts with the small button at the right end.

Now you can even sort the messages based on the attachment's count.